# How to make div scroll instead of exceeding page height? (Bootstrap 5)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

Only the text `foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar` etc. should scroll within the 2 side-by-side divs.

**NOT** the entire page.

How to achieve this?

Things I've tried:

- Setting their `overflow` to `auto` (no effect)
- Additionally setting their height to a hard-coded pixel value (works but cannot use this because the height of the viewer's screen is not known)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='container-fluid h-100'>
      <div class=row>
        <div class=col>
          <audio controls>
            <source src=index.mp3>
           </audio>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=row>
        <div class='col d-flex justify-content-center'>
          <div id=banner>
            <button>Slow / Fast</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=row>
        <div class='col d-flex justify-content-center'>
          <div>
            <div>foo</div>
            <hr>
            <div>bar</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=row>
        <div class='col'>
          <div>foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col'>
          <div>foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can't you use height 100vh?

Comment: Why would I want the 2 bottom divs to be 100% of the screen height?  That would obscure everything else on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we make the whole container fixed, height 100vh and display:flex and wrap the final row in a flexed div we can get it to fill the remaining vertical space in the window and can get it to scroll without moving the first 3 rows.

Here is the altered code:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class='container-fluid h-100' style="position:fixed;display: flex;flex-flow: column;">
          <div class="row" style="flex:0;">
            <div class=col>
              <audio controls>
                <source src=index.mp3>
               </audio>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="flex:0;">
            <div class='col d-flex justify-content-center'>
              <div id=banner>
                <button>Slow / FastSlow</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="flex:0;">
            <div class='col d-flex justify-content-center'>
              <div>
                <div>foo</div>
                <hr>
                <div>bar</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style="overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;">
          <div class="row">
            <div class='col'>
              <div>foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col'>
              <div>foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    
    </html>
```

Note there is some loss of generality as the first 3 rows - the non-moving part - are now set to flex:0